# Synergy: modifier keys not stable on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, synergy

I am using Synergy 1.4.16 with a Windows 7 server and an OS X client. Whenever I hold ctrl, alt or command on the OS X screen the system seems to act like I'm repeating pressing that key instead of holding it. In this way it becomes a challenge to CMD+Click anything.

Does anyone know how to fix this?